# $G$-invariant de Rham theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $M$ be a compact manifold, de Rham theorem   asserts that this is an isomorphism between de Rham cohomology and singular cohomology. Suppose that $M$ admits a smooth group $G$, where $G$ is a compcat Lie group. We can define the complex of $G$-invaraint forms with differential whose cohomology is denoted by $H^{*,G}_{dR}(M)$; and complex of $G$-invariant cochain with real coefficient, whose  cohomology is denoted by $H^{*,G}(M)$.

I guess that $H^{*,G}_{dR}(M)\cong H^{*,G}(M)$.

**Q**  1. Did someone already show this(any reference), or its proof is exactly the same as the de Rham Theorem? (I can not image any obstruction)

or

2. It is wrong, with a counter-example?

Comment: The complex of invariant $H^{*,G}_{dR}(M)$ is isomorphic to $H^*_{dR}(M)$, at least if $G$ is compact: You prove this by averaging a form over the group action.

Comment: If $G$ is not compact, clearly the result is not true, as we can see from the real number line.

Comment: @Thomas Rot for this you need the group to be compact and *path connected*. The action of a finite group on itself is a counter example otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Ben McKay and S. Carmeli.

Comment: @ThomasRot So, do you think it is true/ trivial?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the result is due to Elie Cartan, and the proof is as stated by Thomas Rot.

Comment: Georges de Rham spelled his last name with a space in it, I think, so your title is misspelled.

Comment: @Ben thanks a lot

Comment: @BenMcKay As you mentioned that there is a counterexample for  non-compact $G$, when $G=\mathbb R$, what is the cpt  manifold?

Comment: We can take the real projective line, with the real numbers acting on it by translation in an affine chart, and fixing infinity. Invariant 1-forms are translation invariant on the affine line, but then cannot extend to infinity smoothly without vanishing everywhere. Hence the invariant forms are precisely the constant functions.

Answer (score 1):

A reference for the proof (from the n-lab entry): Eckhard Meinrenken, *Equivariant cohomology and the Cartan model*, in: **Encyclopedia of Mathematical Physics**, Pages 242-250 Academic Press 2006 (pdf, doi:10.1016/B0-12-512666-2/00344-8) http://www.math.toronto.edu/mein/research/enc.pdf

The proof is as indicated by Thomas Rot, and requires the group to be compact and connected.

Comment: I’m not sure this has the (dR-side) result and proof alluded to by @ThomasRot. On the other hand, I think Chevalley-Eilenberg ([1948](//doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1948-0024908-8)) have it as Theorem 2.3, attributing the method to, as you said, Cartan ([1930](//zbmath.org/?q=an:56.0371.02)).